# Android studio jetpack compose native c++ doesnt work preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

if I insert just the line "home" in the preview, then everything works
if I insert the line stringFromJNI from native-lib.cpp then there is a render error
, but if I run the app on a real device, then everything works great

I understand that the fact is that during the preview, android studio cannot load the jni library

```
companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("myapplication")
        }
    }
```

how to make the jni library load during preview rendering

```
``//MainActivity2.kt
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameter
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewParameterProvider
import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme

external fun stringFromJNI(): String
private var strin: String = stringFromJNI()


`class MainActivity2 : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("myapplication")
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting(strin)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

class JStringProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<String> {
    override val values: Sequence<String> = sequenceOf(stringFromJNI())
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {

    MyApplicationTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            Greeting(strin)
        }
    }
}``
`
```

```
//native-lib.cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>



extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity2Kt_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    std::string hello = "Andr";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AAqN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXkmb.png)
on the first picture there is a kotlin string
on the second picture there is a c++ string

I think it's about the library, since the preview works with regular strings
and the strings from native-lib work on a real device.